# Committing a folder with GitHub for Mac

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I attempted to commit a folder using GitHub desktop and got this:

[image]

I then attempted to commit it using terminal and I got a weird folder image I cannot click on. If I click on last commit I see

```
+Subproject commit 13f1a964a7f84fe975ab2959f4a274f2fa7da53d
```

Comment: How exactly did you try to commit your folder from the terminal? What was the command that you used? Does your folder contain any files, or is it just empty?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an empty folder, it has 50+ files.

```
git add pdfjs 
git commit -m "added pdfjs"
git push -u origin master
```